# Can't login into samba share

Tags: samba

I recently reinstalled ubuntu on my laptop and I can no longer log into my samba share on my server. it works on my windows machine and it did work on my laptop before I reinstalled the OS.

I set it to guest access and it still isn't letting me in, I'm lost on whats wrong.

Comment: When you say "it works on my windows machine", do you mean the windows machine can access the share or is your server the windows machine? Do you even see the share in Nautilus on your laptop? It is difficult to give advise/suggestions without knowing the content of smb.conf of your server.

Comment: the samba instance is on my linux server, and my windows desktop can access it just fine, but on my ubuntu laptop, it won't log in. the username/password its using it a samba account on the server.

Comment: I've decided to just access the samba share from sftp. It gives me the same effect as I can connect to the server from my file manager, which is really all I need, thanks to everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tons of differences between how SMB client working on linux/Mac OS and on Windows.

On Linux/Mac:

1. You need to specify share folder smb://SERVER/**SareFolder**
2. You can't just use email addresses like on windows to login, there is a wrapper for GUI working like:

   - mount_smbfs //user@SERVER/folder ./mntpoint
   - Ofc it's can't parse @ sign in login

Comment: Not sure how this helps the poster? As he had a working situation, i am sure he knows how to mount the share.

Comment: "It is difficult to give advise/suggestions without knowing the content of smb.conf of your server" like u says before... i just guessing, there is a tons of thing what user my provide to help us... Because in different versions of Ubuntu we have different versions of samba... i just wrote stuff what my help user in some cases...

Comment: Actually that should have a Comment then, but you can't enter comments yet.